# C# Efficiently replacing -Infinity values in a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, iterator

I have code that uses LINQ converts an dictionary of string, ints to string, doubles. The following code works fine:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, int[]> ret = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();

    int[] a = {1,2,0,4,5};
    int[] b = { 0, 6, 9, 0, 12 };
    int[] c = {2,0,3,5,0};
    ret.Add("Al", a);
    ret.Add("Adam", b);
    ret.Add("Axel", c);

    Dictionary<string, double[]> scores = ret.ToDictionary(r=> r.Key,
                         r => r.Value.Select((v, index)=> 
                         3 * Math.Log10((double)v / 10)
                         ).ToArray());


    foreach (var item in scores)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < item.Value.Length; i ++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", item.Key, item.Value[i]);
        }

    }
```

This code outputs:

```
Key = Al, Value = -3
Key = Al, Value = -2.09691001300806
Key = Al, Value = -Infinity
Key = Al, Value = -1.19382002601611
Key = Al, Value = -0.903089986991944
Key = Adam, Value = -Infinity
Key = Adam, Value = -0.665546248849069
Key = Adam, Value = -0.137272471682025
Key = Adam, Value = -Infinity
Key = Adam, Value = 0.237543738142874
Key = Axel, Value = -2.09691001300806
Key = Axel, Value = -Infinity
Key = Axel, Value = -1.56863623584101
Key = Axel, Value = -0.903089986991944
Key = Axel, Value = -Infinity
```

What is the most efficient way to change -Infinity to 0? Would putting a `continue` or `if statement` function in the loop work? I know I can just use the replace function and loop through the dictionary, which is not very efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have control of the values being put into the dictionary, I'd change

```
(v, index) => 3 * Math.Log10((double)v / 10)
```

to

```
(v, index) => v == 0 ? 0 : 3 * Math.Log10((double)v / 10)
```

Otherwise, you can just use the [ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", item.Key,
    item.Value[i] == Double.NegativeInfinity ? 0 : item.Value[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

People using linq as a single liner often. Forgetting what

```
var scores = ret.ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.Value.Select((v, index)=>
{
    var result = 3 * Math.Log10((double)v / 10);
    if(double.IsNegative(result))
        result = 0;
    return result;
}).ToArray());
```